# How to get key for value in map?

Tags: elixir

Example:

```
map = %{a: 'apple', o: 'orange'}
```

Given the map above I want to get the key for the value `'orange'`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get the key of a specific value in a map, you could do the ff:

```
map
|> Enum.find(fn {key, val} -> val == 'orange' end)
|> elem(0)
```

The above returns `:o`. Note that there's no function in standard lib that does this for us. This is likely because we are not meant to get the key based on the value in a map. It's always much more performant to get the value based on the key. Maybe you could rethink how you use the map and find a way to make `'orange'` the key.

By the way, you are using a char list for `'orange'` instead of a `"string"`.

Comment: Thanks! I am writing my very first program in elixir. Part of why I asked a question was that maybe I could get some better data structure/solution proposal. Oh yes. Elixir strings.

Comment: Please edit the answer to add `_key` instead `key`. As `key` is not being used, you have to place an underscore at the beginning. 

```elixir
map
|> Enum.find(fn {_key, val} -> val == 'orange' end)
|> elem(0)
```